# Finding Dirac Hamiltonian from Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation

My question is can we get the Hamiltonain from Dirac Equation?
We have the following for Dirac equation:

$$(i\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu-m)\phi=0.$$

Then separating the time and space components:

$$(i\gamma ^0 \partial_0-i\gamma ^i \partial_i-m)\phi=0.$$

Then I try to write it in form $i\partial_0\phi=H_D\phi$  so if i take time component to one side and take the i components to the other side:

$$i\gamma^0\partial_0\phi=(i\gamma^i\partial_i+m)\phi.$$

now is it right or should I multiply everything by $\gamma^0$? If I try to do that i get nothing like the dirac hamiltonian. any help is appreciated. Thank you.

PS. this question is from chapter 10 of Matthew Schwartz *Quantum field theory and the Standard model* Problem 10.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43502/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "*If I try to do that i get nothing like the dirac hamiltonian*" - $\beta = \gamma^0, \gamma^i = \beta\alpha_i$